# QNX: QNX 6.5.0 : Cannot find utility PPS

Tags: qnx-neutrino, pps

I currently have above version of qnx running on my target, but i cannot find pps utility. I have checked the file system but it is not available.

How can test this feature of QNX on my target?, Is there any way to install only PPS utility without updating my QNX 6.5.0 to 7.0.0. ?

Comment: PPS is available for QNX 6.5.0 (http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_pps%2Fpps.html), however if you can't find it it means that your QNX build doesn't include it, if you built the qnx version you have yourself you need to include PPS in your build